# How do I set minimum length of my Simple_Form textarea? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am curious about how we should change the validation setting of Simple_form so it allows me to set a minlength for my textarea. How shall we manage to do that? Thank you!

Comment: I wanted to try :input_html => {:minlength => 10}, but clearly its not the correct way. In fact, by default there is no minlength to textarea. I might have to use js for it. I just wonder if there is a better, much cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: btw, i also used :pattern => ".{10,}" without success

Answer (score 0):

No, simple form doesn't provide any validation for `textarea`. You have to use javascript, i guess `jquery-validation` will perfectly fits here.

It is worth mentioning that you can take advantage of HTML5 validation attribute i.e `maxlength` for text area.

And, in case if you don't know to generate required `textarea` wrapper... this is how

```
<%= f.input :name , as: :text , :input_html => {:minlength => 10 , maxlength: 25}   %>
```

Comment: May you elaborate how to corporate this jquery-validation with flash message in the controller, please?

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org , it is client side validation plugin. Since, it is client side validation it has no involvement of server side `flash`

Comment: oh, i see. thank you! But this will duplicate some code for error or success message handling. I hoped if it could be some ways that the feedback can be handled by the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ruby on rails. You can easily create a form in your template view as follows

```
...
<%= form_tag(your_tag, method: "post") do |f| %>
<%= label_tag('your_textarea_tag', "Test:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag('your_textarea_tag', nil, required: true, minlength: 2 , maxlength: 100, size: 100) %>
<% end %>
...
```

`required` is to make sure it is not empty.
`minlength` and `maxlength` controls the length of the content.
`label_tag` and `label_tag` is derived from `actionview` which is included in rails.